# Excel easy : in what way is my simple formula wrong?

Tags: excel, cell, formula

[image]

So my understanding of my formula is:

1. take cells B42,C42, D42 and E42.
2. in that query, limit search to non blank cells.
3. find the smallest value out of those cells

As far as I know excel it simply should be "4", not "1". So there must be something wrong with that `NOT(ISBLANK(ref))` formula, and I would like to know what.

Basically my whole assignment was, to extend the search from B42 to N42. But it my formula is wrong because I'm searching the smallest number in these cells but formula is calculating something different.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your formula works (should be evaluted with array entry - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=MIN(NOT(ISBLANK(B42:E42)))
```

- `ISBLANK(B42:E42)` returns array `{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`
- `NOT({FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE})` returns array `{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}`
- `MIN({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}) returns 1 because`TRUE`in excel equals to`1`

if you're using your formula *without* array entry, you get:

- `ISBLANK(B42:E42)` evaluates to `ISBLANK(#VALUE!)` because it should accept single cell instead range.
- `ISBLANK(#VALUE!)` returns `FALSE`
- `NOT(FALSE)` returns `TRUE`
- `MIN(TRUE)` returns `1` because `TRUE` in excel equals to `1`

You should use

```
=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B42:E42)),B42:E42))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

or simply:

```
=MIN(B42:E42)
```

**UPD:**

if *all cells* in target range are blank, above formulas still returns `0`, in that case you could use:

```
=IF(COUNT(B42:E42),MIN(B42:E42),"")
```

Comment: what would i have to do, to extend that formula to the empty cells:
like from B42 to N42 ... so that it would ignore the empty cells?

Comment: you should use `=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B42:N42)),B42:N42))` and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate the formula or simply `=MIN(B42:N42)`

Comment: OK, so something tells me my excel or more likely "me" is doing something wrong because after i evaluate the formula, the result spews out "0" which with my limited knowledge of excel implies, that formula did not ignore empty cells :

Comment: use `=IF(COUNT(B42:N42),MIN(B42:N42),"")`

Comment: I've used your formula. It's totaly fine for filled cells, but once you include empty cells, all my tries with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER have resulted in "0".

Here, i've posted a picture:
[pic](http://i.imgur.com/Ik7dE9N.jpg)

Comment: it seems that in your hidden columns (between E and N) you have cell with value `0`

Comment: ok so I had these cells with zeroes in between, like a stupid man I am but once i deleted them all and pasted the formula again, "0" again :(

Comment: it can't be possible, formula `=IF(COUNT(B42:N42),MIN(B42:N42),"")` returns `0` only in case when range `B42:N42` contains `0`. Can you give a screen of entire range `B42:N42`?

Comment: funny. you're solution works from B42 to L42.. but when M42 comes up.. it's "0" again. Strange.. i'll dig some more.

I've already vertified your help, because you've done great job so far!

Comment: it was =M42. But anyways.. congrats man :DD

I now remember what i did. I was doing this yesterday. And somehow I put zeroes inside M42 and N42, then went to format cells, and formatter those zeroes to be "hidden" :D No wonder it's been such a headache, i just forgot I hid them.. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

IsBlank is returning either True (aka 1) or False (aka 0).

Try a simple `min(B42:E42)`

Comment: yes this was my initial formula. BUT i have to further the formula to the empty cells, so if I want to IGNORE the empty cells, when i want to calculate the MIN(B42:N42) i would have to include that formula or something in it.

Comment: As far as i've been doing it so far, it does not ignore empty cells :( I'll check again in an instant.)

Answer (score 2):

`ISBLANK` actually returns TRUE or FALSE, which is 1 or 0 in excel. You probably meant to use something like this:

```
=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B42:E42)), B42:E42))
```

But that is an array formula and you have to array enter this formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.... you can use something shorter and simpler with:

```
=MIN(B42:E42)
```

Since `MIN` will automatically ignore blanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(B42:E42<>"",B42:E42))
```

Be sure to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to make it work.